# cannot convert imu messages from bagfile to csv file

Tags: imu, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert this bagfile to csv:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/tie8svln73ii3ii/imu.bag

With this command:

> rostopic echo -b imu.bag -p /android/imu

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/rostopic", line 35, in <module>
    rostopic.rostopicmain()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1666, in rostopicmain
    _rostopic_cmd_echo(argv)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 1026, in _rostopic_cmd_echo
    _rostopic_echo(topic, callback_echo, bag_file=options.bag)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 671, in _rostopic_echo
    _rostopic_echo_bag(callback_echo, bag_file)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py", line 649, in _rostopic_echo_bag
    for t, msg, timestamp in b.read_messages():
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2062, in read_messages
    yield self.seek_and_read_message_data_record((entry.chunk_pos, entry.offset), raw)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2198, in seek_and_read_message_data_record
    msg_type = _get_message_type(connection_info)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1309, in _get_message_type
    message_type = genpy.dynamic.generate_dynamic(info.datatype, info.msg_def)[info.datatype]
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/dynamic.py", line 151, in generate_dynamic
    for l in msg_generator(msg_context, spec, search_path):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 733, in msg_generator
    genmsg.msg_loader.load_depends(msg_context, spec, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 344, in load_depends
    return load_msg_depends(msg_context, spec, msg_search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 313, in load_msg_depends
    depspec = load_msg_by_type(msg_context, resolved_type, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 119, in load_msg_by_type
    file_path = get_msg_file(package_name, base_type, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 78, in get_msg_file
    % (base_type, package, search_path))
Cannot locate message [Header]: unknown package [std_msgs] on search path [{}]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108956/cannot-convert-imu-messages-from-bagfile-to-csv-file/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosjava implementation used in the android sensors app is broken and is not properly embedding the message definitions in the message stream. rosbag then doesn't know how what a std_msgs message type is inside the bagfile. UGH!

My work around was to play the messages with 'rosbag play /android/imu' and then echo the messages to a text file with 'rostopic echo /android/imu > imu.txt'. rostopic doesn't use the message type information located withing the topic stream, but rather uses the compiled libraries, so this works.

Then I convert the text file to a csv file with this ugly shinanigans:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp $1 a

tr -d "[a-z:_/ ,]" < a > b
sed 's/0.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0//' b > a
tr  -s "\n" "," < a > b
sed 's/,---,/#/g' b > a
tr  "#" "\n" < a > b
sed 's/^,//g' b > a

cp a $2
rm a b
```

Save it as a script and run it with './script.bash imu.txt imu.csv' to convert imu.txt to a csv file.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-13**:
I ran into this problem enough times to write a primitive script that attempts to embed the msg defs after the fact (by using some ugle rosbag internals). See [rosbag_fixer](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer).

Note: it uses the defs from the machine it's run on, so won't work always.